# Using two states on useEffect, but want to only one be a dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I'm developing a login page in react native, and the client asked for a virtual keyboard in the page, so it's not used the native keyboard. It looks like that:

[image]

And the components hierarchy makes the keyboard component be sibling to the login form component, so I'm capturing the event when a key is pressed in the keyboard and storing it in a state

```
const [pressedKey, setPressedKey] = useState('');
...
<NumericKeyboard
   handleKeyPressed={pressed => {
    setPressedKey(pressed);
   }}
/>
```

This state is passed into the Login Form component:

```
<LoginFormCard insertedKey={pressedKey} />
```

And this prop is used to trigger the useEffect that will make the pressed key insert a number in the input:

```
  useEffect(() => {
if (!passwordActive) {
  setUsername(prev => {
    return prev + insertedKey;
  });
} else {
  setPassword(prev => {
    return prev + insertedKey;
  });
}

return () => {
  console.log('clean');
};
```

}, [insertedKey, passwordActive]);

The issue is: I need to use `passwordActive`, that is the state that says if the user is writing for the username or the password, as a dependency, so when the user press on the password input, the last pressed key is inserted as well. How do I manage the states better or solve that issue in the right "react" way?

Comment: Are you using a state management library?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts no, just react native

Comment: Any chance the event `handleKeyPressed` could replace the `useEffect` such as `handleKeyPressed={pressed => if (!passwordActive) {setUsername(...)} else (setPassword(...)}`? It would avoid the dependency issue, and it does seem possible since both `passwordActive` and `insertedKey` could be available in this event.

Comment: @JohnLi It's rather a better approach than using the useEffect, indeed. I got a solution by transfering the username and password states to the parent component, so I could only manipulate the triggers, without needing to useEffect

Answer (score 0):

Well... is not quite a answear for the issue itself, but rather a better approach for the issue. I had passed the states for the parent component, and it made not really necessary to use useEffect hook, and the code got like:

````
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [passwordActive, setPasswordActive] = useState(false);

  const handleDelete = () => {
    if (!passwordActive) {
      setUsername(prev => prev.slice(0, -1));
    } else {
      setPassword(prev => prev.slice(0, -1));
    }
  };

  const handleInsert = (key: any) => {
    if (passwordActive) {
      setPassword(prev => prev + key);
    } else {
      setUsername(prev => prev + key);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.view}>
      <View style={styles.container_title}>
        <View style={styles.rows}>
          <Text> Logo lanchecard</Text>
          <Text> Texto 2</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.column}>
          <View style={styles.card}>
            <LoginFormCard
              username={username}
              password={password}
              setPasswordActive={setPasswordActive}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.column}>
          <View style={styles.card}>
            <NumericKeyboard
              handleKeyPressed={pressed => {
                handleInsert(pressed);
              }}
              deleteKeyPressed={handleDelete}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}```
````

Comment: Side-note: Could you please clarify the intent behind the `if... else...` inside your first two callback functions? It looks like both cases perform the same action, so it seems like the conditional is unnecessary here.